# all.equal() in R base not returning TRUE

Tags: r, function

I'm wondering why `all.equal()` doesn't return TRUE for the following data:

```
Like.prob = dbinom(x = 0:2, size = 2, prob = .7)
sim.obs   = rbinom(n = 1e6, size = 2, prob = .7)

sim.Like.prob = unname( table(sim.obs) / 1e6 )[1:3]

all.equal(Like.prob, sim.Like.prob, tolerance = .01) ## Here I expect a TRUE
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just ensure that the two elements have the same class before comparing them:

```
class(Like.prob)
class(sim.Like.prob)
all.equal(Like.prob, as.numeric(sim.Like.prob), tolerance = .01)
```

Comment: Hi RockScience, I was wondering if you might know the answer to [*this interesting question*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47857624/r-function-that-uses-its-output-as-its-own-input-repeatedly)?