# R function that uses its output as its own input repeatedly

Tags: r, function, for-loop

Given R function `auto` (below), I was wondering if it might be possible that from the second run of the `for` loop output of `ps` be used as `pr`?

For example, if loop is going to go 3 times (i.e., `length(n) = 3`), then in the first run of the loop `pr`  is used as is, but from the second run the result of `ps` (i.e., `ps(x)`) from the run before takes the place of `pr` up to the number of `length(n)`.

So, after the first run of the `for` loop, each time, `ps(x)` from the previous run takes the role of `pr` for the next run. My ultimate goal is to `curve` the final `ps` obtained in this manner.

```
auto <- function(n, dat){

for(i in 1:length(n)){           
 pr = function(x) dbeta(x, 1, 1)
 lk = function(x) dbinom(dat[i], n[i], x) # So, here first `n = 100` and 
 ps = function(x) pr(x)*lk(x)             # `dat = 55` will go thru first 
  }                                       # round of the loop and produce
 curve(ps)                                # a `ps`. But in the second run of
}                                         # the loop, the `ps` just
# Example of use:                         # produced will be used as `pr`
auto(n = c(100, 50), dat = c(55, 60) )    # for `n = 50` and `dat = 60`
                                          # to produce a new `ps`.
```

Comment: Are you asking how to write a recursive function?

Comment: I don't understand the question, but here's an example of a recursively defined function: `factorial <- function(x) if (x==0) return(1) else return(x*factorial(x-1)); factorial(5)` . These usually aren't efficient in R, and there's a limit to the stack depth.

Comment: Do you want to return a `function` from a `function`? if yes, then you can return only 1 function. The `ps` in your post. What's problem now?

Comment: I think he want to change function in `for` operator from run after run

Comment: @morouzian functions in R are not finite state automation. And you have no `yield` keyword like in C# for state saving. Possibly, you could use function name and call in by name using `do.call` operator in your fuction code.

Comment: @morouzian If noone give you a solution, I would try to do this later (1-2 hours). Sorry, need to do some business.

Comment: @morouzian I think you have made it more complicated by declaring `pr`, `lk` and `ps`. Why dont you just use `dbeta` and `dbeta` in your algorithm? May be that will be simpler.

Comment: @morouzian Sure. I'll give it a try after 2 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to give an answer.

So, firstly, I thought, that you need finite state automata function. This approach needs to use environment usage in which you need to store state and values for your functions call.
But, you need only make choice based on your cycle index value.
It's much easier, because you need only `switch` operator and nothing more.

```
auto <- function(n, dat, n.loop){
x <- 0.1;
for(i in 1:n.loop){
val <- switch(i, dbeta(x, 1, 1), dbinom(dat, n, x), dbeta(x, 1, 1)*dbinom(dat, n, x))
print(val);
  }
}

auto(n = 100, dat = 55, n.loop = 3)
```

I have 2 questions which should reorganize code well.
1) What is an `x` value which you use in auto? This is not an argument in your code, so, you should determine value of `x` in `auto` directly. Maybe is this an argument?
2) What value does your function need to return as a value?

So, `x <- 0.1` and `print(val)` were added for checking code execution.

Comment: @rnorouzian I'll improve my code soon - need to change location.) So, you'll give correct code for your task.))

Comment: @rnorouzian Now you've puzzled me a little. From your post I could suggest that you need to change not only function, but also an argument like this `x => y = pr(x); y => z = lk(y); z => s = pr(z)*lk(z)?

Comment: @rnorouzian Nope, I'll wait. Possible, I'll rewrite my answer in the morning. Hope, I could help you for a little. See you soon.

Answer (score 0):

I thought to use a different way. Although, I have not completed it but still thought to share with others for improvement ideas. I'm looking at very basic and crude way to solve it.

```
auto <- function(n, dat){
  pr = function(x) dbeta(x, 1, 1)
  lk = function(x) dbinom(dat[1], n[1], x)
  ps = function(x) pr(x)*lk(x) 
  #keep the funtion till now in psold 
  psold = ps
  #loop through 2nd to 2nd last element
  for(i in 2:length(n)-1){
    lk = function(x) dbinom(dat[i], n[i], x)
    #Use psold to evaluate new function ps
    ps = function(x) psold(x)*lk(x)
    psold = ps
  }
  lk = function(x) dbinom(dat[length(n)], n[length(n)], x)
  #Finaly function to be returned.
  ps = function(x) psold(x)*lk(x)  
}
# Example of use:
auto(n = c(100, 50), dat = c(55, 60) )
```

Comment: Thank you so much but if you try to plot the final `ps` using:  `curve(ps)`, you get the following error: `Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?`

Comment: @morouzian Yea. I saw that now. I'm trying to figure out why it leading to too deep nesting. Maybe debug is next option.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand the problem. I added an if statement in the for loop to check if its the first iteration. If it is, it would define `pr`, by your original statement. if not, define it by pr(x) * the lk(x) function of the previous iteration which subsets by `i-1`. I'm sure I'm missing something here though..

I'm also confused where the x input is coming from.

```
auto <- function(n, dat){

  for(i in 1:length(n)){
    if(i == 1){pr = function(x) dbeta(x, 1, 1)} else{pr = function(x) dbeta(x, 1, 1) * function(x) dbinom(dat[i-1], n[i-1], x)}
    lk = function(x) dbinom(dat[i], n[i], x)
    ps = function(x) pr(x)*lk(x)
  }
  curve(ps)
}
# Example of use:
auto(n = c(100, 50), dat = c(55, 60) )
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get the following error: `Error in dbeta(x, 1, 1) * function(x) dbinom(dat[i - 1], n[i - 1], x) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Comment: can you explain what `x` is?

Comment: @MattW. `pr = function(x) dbeta(x, 1, 1) * function(x) dbinom(dat[i-1], n[i-1], x)` isn't valid - you need to use something like this: `pr = function(x) { dbeta(x, 1, 1) * dbinom(dat[i-1], n[i-1], x) }`

Comment: ah gotcha. Thanks @Dmitriy!